# Conditionally show hide column is not working in SharePoint Online Grid view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, quick-edit

I am conditionally showing and hiding the "Approver Name" column based on the "IsApprovalNeeded" column which is working fine in the form but while we try in grid view it always shows the "Approver Name" column even though "IsApprovalNeeded" is false.

I have used the below formula for this condition:

```
=if([$IsApprovalNeeded]==true,'true','false')
```

This condition works fine in the form:

[image: Conditionally show hide column is not working in SharePoint Online Grid view]

When the user selects "**IsApprovalNeeded**" as false the "**Approver Name**" column is not shown.

But when the "**IsApprovalNeeded**" is true the "**Approver Name**" column is shown.

[image: Conditionally show hide column is not working in SharePoint Online Grid view]

In Grid View, whether the user selects "**IsApprovalNeeded**" is true or false, the "**Approver Name**" column is always shown and the user is able to add the approver name.

[image: Conditionally show hide column is not working in SharePoint Online Grid view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation in SharePoint online.

The conditional formulas does not work with the Grid views (Quick Edit) in lists. The fields will not be hidden while using conditional formula.

**Source**: [How to hide a field in SharePoint lists and libraries with the conditional formula](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-hide-a-field-in-sharepoint-lists-and-libraries-with-the-conditional-formula/)

**Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)